# Searching both sides of a Binary Search Tree in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have a BST in python, with each node holding 3 pieces of data. Those pieces of data being ID, Mark, and Name.

What I'm trying to do is search for a Name, but the nodes are based on IDs, this is how I've searched. The function is supposed to output the ID of the specific Name.

```
def findName(tree,name):
    if tree==None:
        return None
    elif tree['name']==name:
        return tree['id']
    if tree['left']!=None:
        return findName(tree['left'],name)
    if tree['right']!=None:
        return findName(tree['right'],name)
```

Unfortunately I'll only ever be searching the left side of the Tree, and not the right, the opposite applies if I search the right side first.

How do I search both sides for this?

Comment: You can probably just do `if tree['left']:` and `if tree['right']:`, since None evaluates to false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't `return` if you're not yet finished! Instead, you can replace your last 4 lines with a single, short-circuiting `or`:

```
return findName(tree['left'], name) or findName(tree['right'], name)
```

Make sure your IDs don't include `0`, though, otherwise this method will fail because `0` is a falsy value, just like None.

Comment: This will cause one extra level of recursion when one of the branches is None, but should not do any harm since this case is tested for at the start of the function.

Comment: @gnibbler: Yep, I was considering that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
...
result = findName(tree['left'],name)
if result is None:
    result = findName(tree['right'],name) 
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are returning in the

```
if tree['left']!=None:
    return findName(tree['left'],name)
```

What you have to do is create a local variable and set it to the value from `findName()` then if you get None continue with the right otherwise return the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the branches like this if you wish to avoid the extra recursive call. Note that it is preferable to test identity of `None` rather than equality

```
for branch in ('left', 'right'):
    if tree[branch] is not None:
        result = findName(tree[branch], name)
        if result is not None:
            return result
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def search(node, name):
    self_result = [node['id']] if node['name'] == name else []
    if not node['left'] and not node['right']:
        return self_result
    elif node['left'] and not node['right']:
        return self_result + search(node['left'], name)
    elif not node['left'] and node['right']:
        return self_result + search(node['right'], name)
    else:
        return self_result + search(node['left'], name) + search(node['right'], name)

test_tree = {'id':0, 'name': 'a', 
             'left': {'id':1, 'name': 'a', 
                      'left':{'id':3, 'name':'c', 
                              'left':{'id':4,'name': 'd', 
                                  'left' : None,
                                  'right' : None},
                          'right':None},
                  'right':{'id':4, 'name':'e',
                           'left': None,
                           'right': None}
                  }, 
             'right': {'id':5, 'name':'c',
                       'left': {'id':6, 'name':'e',
                                'left': None,
                                'right': None},
                       'right': {'id': 7, 'name': 'a',
                                 'left' : {'id' : 8, 'name': 'b',
                                           'left': None,
                                           'right' : None},
                                 'right' : None
                                }
                      }
            }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert search(test_tree, 'a') == [0, 1, 7]
    assert search(test_tree, 'b') == [8]
    assert search(test_tree, 'c') == [3, 5]
    assert search(test_tree, 'e') == [4, 6]
    print 'ok'
```

It can also deal with multiple matches.